# return type hashtable in extended method

Tags: java, hashset, extending

I have an interface Node that asks for the method:

`public HashSet getNeighbour();`

NodeVariable implements Node, and its neighbours are of type NodeFunction (that implements Node, too), and I wrote the method:

`public HashSet<NodeFunction> getNeighbour();`

(and viceversa in NodeFunction class).

I found out that if I change the signature of method in Node to:

`public HashSet<Node> getNeighbour();`

then on the methods in NodeVariable and NodeFunction I get the error:

> Error getNeighbour() in factorgraph.NodeFunction cannot implement getNeighbour() in factorgraph.Node   return type java.util.HashSet is not compatible with java.util.HashSet NodeFunction.java

This is not really clear.

I found:

[Overriding return type in extended interface - Bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864557/overriding-return-type-in-extended-interface-bad-idea)

and

[Java - Overriding return type of extended interface when return type uses generics for own method parameter types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056595/java-overriding-return-type-of-extended-interface-when-return-type-uses-generi)

and now I changed the Node method signature in:

`public HashSet<? extends Node> getNeighbour();`

thus the compiler stops complaining.

Is it right? Why HashSet is not considered like an "extension" of HashSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashSet<Node>` and `HashSet<NodeFunction>` aren't compatible, even though `NodeFunction` implements/subclasses `Node`. Similarly, neither are `List<Number>` and `List<Integer>`. `Integer` subclasses `Number`.

```
static List<Number> getNumberList(int size) {
    //ArrayList<Integer> numList = null; //Doesn't compile
    ArrayList<Number> numList = null; //Compiles
    return numList;
}
```

If the compiler allowed what your trying to do, then I could do the following and a `ClassCastException` would be thrown, which is the exact reason generics was created.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Node nd = getInstance();
        Set<Node> ndSet = nd.getNeighbour();
        ndSet.add( new NodeSign() );
        nd.removeSingleNeighbor(); //throws ClassCastException
    }

    static Node getInstance() {
        return new NodeVariable();
    }
}

interface Node {
    public Set<Node> getNeighbour();
    public void removeSingleNeighbor();
}

class NodeVariable implements Node {
    Set<NodeFunction> ndFuncList = new HashSet<NodeFunction>();
    public Set<NodeFunction> getNeighbour(){ return ndFuncList; } //wont' compile

    //HERE!!!!

    public void removeSingleNeighbor() { 
        NodeFunction ndFunc = (NodeFunction)ndFuncList.toArray()[ndFuncList.size()-1]; //throws ClassCastException
    }
}

class NodeFunction implements Node {
    public Set<NodeFunction> getNeighbour(){ return null; } //won't compile
    public void removeSingleNeighbor() {}
}

class NodeSign implements Node {
    public Set<NodeFunction> getNeighbour(){ return null; } //won't compile
    public void removeSingleNeighbor() {}
}
```

Everything is semantically/syntactically valid except `public Set<NodeFunction> getNeighbour(){}`. The Java tutorials cover [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html) issue.

Comment: This is pretty clear.
Your link, also, give me the complete explanation.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's a better idea to define the methods in your interfaces in terms of other interfaces and not concrete implementations. What I want to say is that the `getNeighbour()` method should be:

```
public Set getNeighbour();
```

And since we know that it can only return Nodes (or subtypes of Node), we might as well define it like this:

```
public Set<? extends Node> getNeighbour();
```

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that <? extends Node> is the right way. I'm going to change HashSet with Set. Thank you!